# What is the UserMixin in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, mixins, flask-login

```py
from datetime import datetime
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from app import db


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User{}>'.format(self.username)
```

After reading [the official documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) I couldn't yet understand the purpose of `UserMixin`. Can anyone please describe it in brief?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class)?

Comment: Yup but couldn't understand it that well

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Flask-login requires a User model with the following properties:

- has an is_authenticated() method that returns True if the user has provided valid credentials
- has an is_active() method that returns True if the user’s account is active
- has an is_anonymous() method that returns True if the current user is an anonymous user
- has a get_id() method which, given a User instance, returns the unique ID for that object

UserMixin class provides the implementation of this properties. Its the reason you can call for example `is_authenticated` to check if login credentials provide is correct or not instead of having to write a method to do that yourself.